# Getting a File's MD5 Checksum in Java

Tags: java, md5, checksum

I am looking to use Java to get the MD5 checksum of a file.  I was really surprised but I haven't been able to find anything that shows how to get the MD5 checksum of a file.

How is it done?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/hsqldb/src/org/hsqldb/lib/MD5.java.shtml "MD5 Java") will help. You could also look up the spec but that would take more doing as it's complicated.

Comment: Keep in mind that according to the recent research "MD5 should be considered cryptographically broken and unsuitable for further use". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Comment: MD5 is no longer considered cryptographically secure, but it's still sufficient for validating file consistency and it's faster than SHA.

Comment: @ZakhariaStanley This is a question about checksumming.

Comment: The canonical use for MD5 checksums on files is to avoid hostile replacements of distributed files. That's where it is unsecure.

But in a scenario where hostile exploits are not a concern, it's perfectly suitable.

Answer (score 613, accepted):

There's an input stream decorator, `java.security.DigestInputStream`, so that you can compute the digest while using the input stream as you normally would, instead of having to make an extra pass over the data.

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("file.txt"));
     DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is, md)) 
{
  /* Read decorated stream (dis) to EOF as normal... */
}
byte[] digest = md.digest();
```

Comment: I agree, very elegant way to calculate the checksum on the fly if you're already doing something with the bytes (i.e. reading them in on from an HTTP connection).

Comment: +1 for stream implementation. 
@Marc doesn't have to just be an HTTP stream, java io streams come in about every flavor one can think of; i.e. this method would be handy in a wide variety of scenarios.

Comment: Tried it but, this error occurs Type mismatch: cannot convert from DigestInputStream to FileInputStream why it does not work on my side? I am running on java 1.6

Comment: @AlPhaba Did you declare the `is` as an `InputStream` or a `FileInputStream`? Sounds like you used `FileInputStream`, which would cause this error.

Comment: Is it possible to use this approach for multiple types of digests? For example, if I need both the `MD5` and `SHA1`?

Comment: @carlspring In conjunction with a "tee" input stream, you could. It's not terribly difficult to write one yourself, or use Apache Commons. Here's a [question about that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801901/)

Comment: @erickson, I've actually started a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300774/calculate-multiple-checksums-from-the-same-inputstream-using-digestinputstream . If you have some time, perhaps you could illustrate it for me?

Comment: @barwnikk It works fine in Java 8. `MethodNotFound` is not an exception from standard Java; perhaps you are talking about a compiler error? In any case, if it doesn't work for you, it's a local configuration problem, or a problem with other code.

Comment: @barwnikk Again, that is your local configuration problem. This is valid Java 7 and Java 8 code. If you are stuck with tools from 2006, you'll have to adapt.

Comment: @erickson You are not updating the MessageDigest object with the file content. Rt ? This code will print always a same digest.

Comment: @sunil No. The `MessageDigest` object is updated by the `DigestInputStream`, with all of the data in the file. It will return the same digest only if the file contents are identical (or there's a hash collision, which is practically impossible unless someone exploits the weakness in MD5 intentionally).

Comment: @erickson You were right erickson. I forgot to read the content so that the MessageDigest object is updated. I updated your answer with this change.

Comment: @erickson I was wondering why this function kept returning the same hash, but it seems your last edit (Nov 3) broke the code again. The part "while(dis.read()!= -1);
                dis.close();" should be executed in order to return the right md5.

Comment: @SymenTimmermans Thanks for catching that. My edit should fix that.

Comment: IMO, it's unnecessary in this case to close `is`, as closing `dis` automatically closes `dis`. So, you can move `InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("file.txt"))` out of the `try (...)` (i.e. like this: `MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("file.txt")); try (DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is, md)) 
{...}`). Although, I'm not sure about coding style (maybe, some style guideline requires both `is` and `dis` to be inside `try (...)` -- but it isn't required by the program logic per se).

Comment: Or like this: `MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); try (DigestInputStream is = new DigestInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("file.txt")), md)) {...} byte[] digest = md.digest();`.

Comment: @Sasha What if creation of the digest stream raises an exception? Then the file input stream will not be closed in a timely manner. On the other hand, what harm is there in clearly enforcing the underlying file input stream is to be closed on exiting the `try` block? I don't see any value in this micro-optimization.

Comment: @erickson, "what if creation of the digest stream raises an exception" -- AFAIK, it can't. "I don't see any value in this micro-optimization" -- you're right, there's no value, it's just a matter of code style. (I just wanted to point out that it's not mandatory to close underlying stream, as it's automatically closed by wrapper stream -- it maybe non-obvious for Java-newcomers.)

Comment: But which variable contains MD-5 hash in the end?

Comment: @gstackoverflow The variable `digest`, at the end.

Comment: Its always returning the same result.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi You have to actually read the whole stream inside the `try` block. If your code is not working, you could open your own question with an [mcve] to see where your bug is.

Comment: Ahh I see now.. Missed it as was in a hurry. You should probably fill in that code as well.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Well, the idea behind the Decorator pattern is that any code that works with an `InputStream` will function with this extension, and compute the digest as a side-effect of whatever processing you are normally doing (like uploading the file, parsing it, etc.). I don’t know what processing people will use, so I can’t do their (whole) job for them.

Comment: Does this method consume a lot of memory while calculating MD5 for a large file? Is it recommended if my application is already in serious memory condition?

Comment: @WayneWei No. MD5 hash is a constant space algorithm. It only keeps 16 bytes of state for computation. The implementation might use a 64 byte block buffer internally.

Answer (score 340):

Use [DigestUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) from [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) library:

```
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("file.zip"))) {
    String md5 = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(is);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in my android code I get this error...java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString
at org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(DigestUtils.java:215)

Comment: @JPM Presume you downloaded and put the `commons-codec.jar` on your classpath already?

Comment: yes there and I exported in my android project..I can step through the code and the class is there in the source files...weird, must be some android Eclipse issue.

Comment: I had the same problem, but it fixed by this code `   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
   byte data[] = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5(fis);
   char md5Chars[] = Hex.encodeHex(data);
   String md5 = String.valueOf(md5Chars);`

Comment: Nice!  For new projects I always think twice before adding a new dependency but for existing project I just have to check if the library is already there to use it. +1

Comment: Very nice! Works in MATLAB too... Simply read the file 'fis' and use 'md5 = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(fis);'

Comment: Works well and should be the accepted answer, as the accepted answer is not complete.

Comment: Works for me, but seems to be a little bit slower then the accepted answer.

Answer (score 176):

There's an example at [Real's Java-How-to](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0416.html) using the [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) class.

Check that page for examples using CRC32 and SHA-1 as well.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class MD5Checksum {

   public static byte[] createChecksum(String filename) throws Exception {
       InputStream fis =  new FileInputStream(filename);

       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       MessageDigest complete = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
       int numRead;

       do {
           numRead = fis.read(buffer);
           if (numRead > 0) {
               complete.update(buffer, 0, numRead);
           }
       } while (numRead != -1);

       fis.close();
       return complete.digest();
   }

   // see this How-to for a faster way to convert
   // a byte array to a HEX string
   public static String getMD5Checksum(String filename) throws Exception {
       byte[] b = createChecksum(filename);
       String result = "";

       for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
           result += Integer.toString( ( b[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
       }
       return result;
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       try {
           System.out.println(getMD5Checksum("apache-tomcat-5.5.17.exe"));
           // output :
           //  0bb2827c5eacf570b6064e24e0e6653b
           // ref :
           //  http://www.apache.org/dist/
           //          tomcat/tomcat-5/v5.5.17/bin
           //              /apache-tomcat-5.5.17.exe.MD5
           //  0bb2827c5eacf570b6064e24e0e6653b *apache-tomcat-5.5.17.exe
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: The example at Real's Java-How-To works perfectly, and was simple to implement.

Comment: The read loop is a little clumsy. `read()` won't return zero, and a `do/while` isn't really appropriate.

Comment: byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; can we change the size from 1024 to something more optimal?

Comment: It works just fine, but I would recommend to consider proper `InputStream` closing when implementing it in your project.

Comment: Why do you use the filename and not the blob? How can you ensure that the image is the same if you do not calculate the checksum based on the blob ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa This doesn't use the filename to compute the hash, it uses the contents of the buffer while reading the file.

Comment: Nice complete example and doesn't use up RAM for large files. Also this works out-of-the-box on old versions of Java without anything extra needed.

Answer (score 93):

The [com.google.common.hash](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/package-summary.html) API offers:

- A unified user-friendly API for all hash functions
- Seedable 32- and 128-bit implementations of murmur3
- md5(), sha1(), sha256(), sha512() adapters, change only one line of code to switch between these, and murmur.
- goodFastHash(int bits), for when you don't care what algorithm you use
- General utilities for HashCode instances, like combineOrdered / combineUnordered

Read the User Guide ([IO Explained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/IOExplained), [Hashing Explained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/HashingExplained)).

For your use-case [`Files.hash()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#hash-java.io.File-com.google.common.hash.HashFunction-) computes and returns the digest value for a file.

For example a [sha-1](/questions/tagged/sha-1) digest calculation (change SHA-1 to MD5 to get MD5 digest)

```
HashCode hc = Files.asByteSource(file).hash(Hashing.sha1());
"SHA-1: " + hc.toString();
```

Note that [crc32](/questions/tagged/crc32) is much faster than [md5](/questions/tagged/md5), so use [crc32](/questions/tagged/crc32) if you do not need a cryptographically secure checksum. Note also that [md5](/questions/tagged/md5) should not be used to store passwords and the like since it is to easy to brute force, for passwords use [bcrypt](/questions/tagged/bcrypt),  [scrypt](/questions/tagged/scrypt) or [sha-256](/questions/tagged/sha-256) instead.

For long term protection with hashes a  [Merkle signature scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_signature_scheme) adds to the security and The Post Quantum Cryptography Study Group sponsored by the European Commission has recommended use of this cryptography for long term protection against quantum computers ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-quantum_cryptography#Hash-based_cryptography_.E2.80.93_Merkle_signature_scheme)).

Note that [crc32](/questions/tagged/crc32) has a higher collision rate than the others.

Comment: What part of Files.hash as stated above does not cover Files.hash ?

Comment: The `Files.hash()` is marked as deprecated, the recommended way is: `Files.asByteSource(file).hash(Hashing.sha1())`

Comment: And as of January 2018 `Hashing.sha1()` is marked deprecated. The function `Hashing.sha256()` is recommended instead. [source](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html#sha1--)

Answer (score 84):

Using nio2 (Java 7+) and no external libraries:

```
byte[] b = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/file"));
byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(b);
```

To compare the result with an expected checksum:

```
String expected = "2252290BC44BEAD16AA1BF89948472E8";
String actual = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash);
System.out.println(expected.equalsIgnoreCase(actual) ? "MATCH" : "NO MATCH");
```

Comment: @Arash yes absolutely - thanks. I mixed up the JDK Files class and Guava's.

Comment: I like this solution more than erickson's since it can be wrapped with Optionals to use pure Functional style programming

Comment: For a big file this will use a lot of memory since the whole file is read and then fed to the digest instead of reading chunks and "digesting" them as they are read.

Answer (score 45):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) now provides a new, consistent hashing API that is much more user-friendly than the various hashing APIs provided in the JDK. See [Hashing Explained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained). For a file, you can get the MD5 sum, CRC32 (with version 14.0+) or many other hashes easily:

```
HashCode md5 = Files.hash(file, Hashing.md5());
byte[] md5Bytes = md5.asBytes();
String md5Hex = md5.toString();

HashCode crc32 = Files.hash(file, Hashing.crc32());
int crc32Int = crc32.asInt();

// the Checksum API returns a long, but it's padded with 0s for 32-bit CRC
// this is the value you would get if using that API directly
long checksumResult = crc32.padToLong();
```

Comment: `Files.hash` is deprecated, use `Files.asByteSource(new File("")).hash(Hashing.md5())` now

Answer (score 34):

Ok. I had to add. One line implementation for those who already have Spring and Apache Commons dependency or are planning to add it:

```
DigestUtils.md5DigestAsHex(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file))
```

For and Apache commons only option (credit @duleshi):

```
DigestUtils.md5Hex(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file))
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: It's `DigestUtils.md5Hex(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file))`

Comment: David Onter commons based solution is better because it doesn't read a whole file into memory.

Comment: At least for `Spring 5`  you have `DigestUtils.md5Digest(InputStream inputStream)` to calculate the MD5 digest and `DigestUtils.md5DigestAsHex(InputStream inputStream)` for hexadecimal string representation of the MD5 digest methods without read a whole file into memory.

Answer (score 27):

A simple approach with no third party libraries using Java 7

```
String path = "your complete file path";
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md.update(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
byte[] digest = md.digest();
```

If you need to print this byte array. Use as below

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digest));
```

If you need hex string out of this digest. Use as below

```
String digestInHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest).toUpperCase();
System.out.println(digestInHex);
```

where DatatypeConverter is javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

Comment: Why the `toUpperCase`?

Comment: @edgecaseberg just for the hex string look good while printing it to console

Comment: I found I needed to use toLowerCase() instead of toUpperCase().

Answer (score 14):

I recently had to do this for just a dynamic string, `MessageDigest` can represent the hash in numerous ways. To get the signature of the file like you would get with the **[md5sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum)** command I had to do something like the this:

```
try {
   String s = "TEST STRING";
   MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
   md5.update(s.getBytes(),0,s.length());
   String signature = new BigInteger(1,md5.digest()).toString(16);
   System.out.println("Signature: "+signature);

} catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This obviously doesn't answer your question about how to do it specifically for a file, the above answer deals with that quiet nicely. I just spent a lot of time getting the sum to look like most application's display it, and thought you might run into the same trouble.

Comment: The signature is the digest in hexadecimal format. I too found the hexadecimal representation to work where, as you say, other representations do not work. Thank you for putting this up.

Comment: This is good, but `.toString(16)` will throw away leading zeros. `String.format("%032x", ...)` may be better.

Answer (score 14):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:\\apache\\cxf.jar");

    byte[] dataBytes = new byte[1024];

    int nread = 0;
    while ((nread = fis.read(dataBytes)) != -1) {
        md.update(dataBytes, 0, nread);
    };
    byte[] mdbytes = md.digest();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < mdbytes.length; i++) {
        sb.append(Integer.toString((mdbytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }
    System.out.println("Digest(in hex format):: " + sb.toString());
}
```

Or you may get more info 
http://www.asjava.com/core-java/java-md5-example/

Comment: THIS ANSWER is good I spent 12 hr before use this answer to achieve what i want *many thanks* :)

Answer (score 10):

We were using code that resembles the code above in a previous post using

```
...
String signature = new BigInteger(1,md5.digest()).toString(16);
...
```

However, watch out for using `BigInteger.toString()` here, as it will truncate leading zeros...
(for an example, try `s = "27"`, checksum should be `"02e74f10e0327ad868d138f2b4fdd6f0"`)

I second the suggestion to use Apache Commons Codec, I replaced our own code with that.

Comment: Wow, I was looking into an issue where the MD5 stuff was working perfectly for everything, except a file was giving us only a 31 hex digit output, and was failing the md5checksums. that truncating of leading 0s is a huge pain... Thanks for your note.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a handy variation that makes use of `InputStream.transferTo()` from Java 9, and `OutputStream.nullOutputStream()` from Java 11. It requires no external libraries and does not need to load the entire file into memory.

```
public static String hashFile(String algorithm, File f) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);

    try(BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream((new FileInputStream(f)));
        DigestOutputStream out = new DigestOutputStream(OutputStream.nullOutputStream(), md)) {
        in.transferTo(out);
    }

    String fx = "%0" + (md.getDigestLength()*2) + "x";
    return String.format(fx, new BigInteger(1, md.digest()));
}
```

and

```
hashFile("SHA-512", Path.of("src", "test", "resources", "some.txt").toFile());
```

returns

```
"e30fa2784ba15be37833d569280e2163c6f106506dfb9b07dde67a24bfb90da65c661110cf2c5c6f71185754ee5ae3fd83a5465c92f72abd888b03187229da29"
```

Answer (score 9):

```
public static String MD5Hash(String toHash) throws RuntimeException {
   try{
       return String.format("%032x", // produces lower case 32 char wide hexa left-padded with 0
      new BigInteger(1, // handles large POSITIVE numbers 
           MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(toHash.getBytes())));
   }
   catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      // do whatever seems relevant
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Very fast & clean Java-method that doesn't rely on external libraries:

(Simply replace MD5 with SHA-1, SHA-256, SHA-384 or SHA-512 if you want those)

```
public String calcMD5() throws Exception{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("Path to file")), md);
        try {
            while (dis.read(buffer) != -1);
        }finally{
            dis.close();
        }

        byte[] bytes = md.digest();

        // bytesToHex-method
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }

        return new String(hexChars);
}
```

Comment: The "bytesToHex" bit can be replaced with `new BigInteger(1, bytes).toString(16)`.

Answer (score 8):

```
String checksum = DigestUtils.md5Hex(new FileInputStream(filePath));
```

Answer (score 6):

Another implementation: [Fast MD5 Implementation in Java](http://www.twmacinta.com/myjava/fast_md5.php)

```
String hash = MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(new File(filename)));
```

Comment: I cannot find the method `MD5.asHex()` in JDK 1.8.0 242.

Answer (score 6):

[Standard Java Runtime Environment way](http://vyshemirsky.blogspot.ru/2007/08/computing-md5-digest-checksum-in-java.html):

```
public String checksum(File file) {
  try {
    InputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
    java.security.MessageDigest md5er =
        MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    do {
      read = fin.read(buffer);
      if (read > 0)
        md5er.update(buffer, 0, read);
    } while (read != -1);
    fin.close();
    byte[] digest = md5er.digest();
    if (digest == null)
      return null;
    String strDigest = "0x";
    for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
      strDigest += Integer.toString((digest[i] & 0xff) 
                + 0x100, 16).substring(1).toUpperCase();
    }
    return strDigest;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

The result is equal of linux md5sum utility.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple function that wraps around Sunil's code so that it takes a File as a parameter. The function does not need any external libraries, but it does require Java 7.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Checksum {

    /**
     * Generates an MD5 checksum as a String.
     * @param file The file that is being checksummed.
     * @return Hex string of the checksum value.
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static String generate(File file) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,IOException {

        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        messageDigest.update(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest();

        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash).toUpperCase();
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        File file = new File("/Users/foo.bar/Documents/file.jar");          
        String hex = Checksum.generate(file);
        System.out.printf("hex=%s\n", hex);            
    }


}
```

Example output:

```
hex=B117DD0C3CBBD009AC4EF65B6D75C97B
```

Comment: This all nice when you use small files. For a 5gb file you'd be reading all of it into RAM, and as the docs state `It is not intended for reading in large files.`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ANT to build, this is dead-simple.  Add the following to your build.xml:

```
<checksum file="${jarFile}" todir="${toDir}"/>
```

Where jarFile is the JAR you want to generate the MD5 against, and toDir is the directory you want to place the MD5 file.

[More info here.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/checksum.html)

Answer (score 3):

Google guava provides a new API. Find the one below :

```
public static HashCode hash(File file,
            HashFunction hashFunction)
                     throws IOException

Computes the hash code of the file using hashFunction.

Parameters:
    file - the file to read
    hashFunction - the hash function to use to hash the data
Returns:
    the HashCode of all of the bytes in the file
Throws:
    IOException - if an I/O error occurs
Since:
    12.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String getMd5OfFile(String filePath)
{
    String returnVal = "";
    try 
    {
        InputStream   input   = new FileInputStream(filePath); 
        byte[]        buffer  = new byte[1024];
        MessageDigest md5Hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        int           numRead = 0;
        while (numRead != -1)
        {
            numRead = input.read(buffer);
            if (numRead > 0)
            {
                md5Hash.update(buffer, 0, numRead);
            }
        }
        input.close();

        byte [] md5Bytes = md5Hash.digest();
        for (int i=0; i < md5Bytes.length; i++)
        {
            returnVal += Integer.toString( ( md5Bytes[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
        }
    } 
    catch(Throwable t) {t.printStackTrace();}
    return returnVal.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pulling together ideas from other answers, here's simple code with no third party dependencies (or DatatypeConverter which is longer in the latest JDKs) that generates this as a hex string compatible with output of the md5sum tool:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
...

static String calculateMD5(String path) throws IOException
{
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
        return String.format("%032x", new BigInteger(1, md.digest())); // hex, padded to 32 chars
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex); // MD5 is always available so this should be impossible
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Matches md5sum.