# Measure disk write/read speed using java

Tags: java, performance, io, sigar

How to measure  write/read disc speed using java, i know about SIGAR library, but i can't found such methods  in there. Maybe someone know solution?

The problem is that I need to determine at what rate currently is writing to disk, and at what speed is being read. Furthermore, ideally, the data must be obtained for specific directories. But if you tell me at least how to define the entire disk would be very grateful.

Comment: I have an answer to this question that might be your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731701/how-to-measure-disk-speed-in-java-for-benchmarking/36523488#36523488
I've posted a project on disk sourceforge called jdiskmark with code you can look at on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you obtain this information is entirely dependant on the operating system.

On Linux the simplest tool is to use `iostat` which will show you how much read/write in blocks and count for each file system.

Performance measurements on a per directory basis are not very meaningful as file systems are not implemented that way.  You write to files which can be anywhere on disk and these files might appear in one or more directories.  The files are not physically arranged by directory.

Comment: I need this information for Windows. Thank you for clarifying the situation, the relationship between directories and files.

Comment: In that case you need an equivalent tool for windows.