# Java benchmark disk speed

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking

I'm trying to get some reliable method of measuring disk read speed, but failing at removal of cache out of the equation.

In [How to measure Disk Speed in Java for Benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731701/how-to-measure-disk-speed-in-java-for-benchmarking) is in answer from simgineer utility for exactly this, but for some reason, I failed to replicate its behaviour, and running the utility does not yield anything precise either (for read).

From suggestion in different answer, setting test file to something bigger than main memory size seems to work, but I cannot afford to spend whole four minutes for system to allocate 130GB file. (not writing anything in the file results in sparse file and returns bogus times)

Sufficient file size seems to be somewhere between

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()
```

and

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()*2
```

The source code of my current solution:

```
File file = new File(false ? "D:/work/bench.dat" : "./work/bench.dat");
RandomAccessFile wFile = null, rFile = null;
try {
    System.out.println("Allocating test file ...");
    int blockSize = 1024*1024;
    long size = false ? 10L*1024L*(long)blockSize : Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()*2;
    byte[] block = new byte[blockSize];
    for(int i = 0; i<blockSize; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) block[i] = (byte) (i & 0xFF);
    }

    System.out.println("Writing ...");
    wFile = new RandomAccessFile(file,"rw");
    wFile.setLength(size);
    for(long i = 0; i<size-blockSize; i+= blockSize) {
        wFile.write(block);
    }
    wFile.close();

    System.out.println("Running read test ...");
    long t0 = System.nanoTime();

    rFile = new RandomAccessFile(file,"r");
    int blockCount = (int)(size/blockSize)-1;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i<testCount; i++) {
        rFile.seek((long)rnd.nextInt(blockCount)*(long)blockSize);
        rFile.readFully(block, 0, blockSize);
    }
    rFile.close();

    long t1 = System.nanoTime();

    double readB = ((double)testCount*(double)blockSize);
    double timeNs = (double)(t1-t0);

    return (readB/(1024*1024))/(timeNs/(1000*1000*1000));
} catch (Exception e) {
    Logger.logError("Failed to benchmark drive speed!", e);
    return 0;
} finally {
    if(wFile != null) {try {wFile.close();} catch (IOException e) {}}
    if(rFile != null) {try {rFile.close();} catch (IOException e) {}}
    if(file.exists()) {file.delete();}
}
```

I somewhat hoped to get a benchmark that will finish within seconds (caching results for following runs) having only first execution **a bit** slower.

I could technically crawl the filesystem and bench the read on files that are already on the drive, but that smells like a lot of undefined behaviour and firewalls are not happy about it either.

Any other options left? (platform dependent libraries are off the table)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but you can only "cache", what you know. If you read a file, you have to read the file from disk since the content of the file is unknown. Therefore there is no caching effect (provided the file was not loaded in RAM before).

Comment: Both read and written files go to cache. Anyway, I can assure you there is something fishy about getting 2GB/s reads from mechanical drive. As I mentioned, large enough file will result in read speeds corresponding to disk specs.

Comment: Can you open the whole d: drive and read random sectors in java? We do this in c++ but not sure if this is possible in java.

Comment: You cannot call windows API directly in java. Would have to use JNI, and there goes the platform-independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end decided to solve the problem by scouring local work folder for files and load those, hoping we packaged enough with application to get specs speeds. In my current test case, the answer is luckily yes, but there are no guarantees, so I keep the approach from question as a backup plan.

This is not exactly perfect solution, but it somewhat works, getting specs speed at about 2000 test files. Bear in mind that this test cannot be rerun with same results, as all test files from previous execution are now probably cached.

You can always call flushmem ( https://chadaustin.me/flushmem/ ) by Chad Austin, but that takes about as much time to execute as the original approach, so I would advise to simply cache result of the first run and hope for the best.

Used code:

```
final int MIN_FILE_SIZE = 1024*10;
final int MAX_READ = 1024*1024*50;
final int FILE_COUNT_FRACTION = 4;

// Scour the location of the runtime for any usable files.
ArrayList<File> found = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<File> queue = new ArrayList<>();
queue.add(new File("./"));
while(!queue.isEmpty() && found.size() < testCount) {
    File tested = queue.remove(queue.size()-1);
    if(tested.isDirectory()) {
        queue.addAll(Arrays.asList(tested.listFiles()));
    } else if(tested.length()>MIN_FILE_SIZE){
        found.add(tested);
    }
}

// If amount of found files is not sufficient, perform test with new file.
if(found.size() < testCount/FILE_COUNT_FRACTION) {
    Logger.logInfo("Disk to CPU transfer benchmark failed to find "
            + "sufficient amount of files to read, slow version "
            + "will be performed!", found.size());
    return benchTransferSlowDC(testCount);
}

System.out.println(found.size());

byte[] block = new byte[MAX_READ];
Collections.shuffle(found);
RandomAccessFile raf = null;
long readB = 0;
try {
    long t0 = System.nanoTime();

    for(int i = 0; i<Math.min(found.size(), testCount); i++) {
        File file = found.get(i);
        int size = (int) Math.min(file.length(), MAX_READ);
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(file,"r");
        raf.read(block, 0, size);
        raf.close();
        readB += size;
    }
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();

    return ((double)readB/(1024*1024))/((double)(t1-t0)/(1000*1000*1000));
    //return (double)(t1-t0) / (double)readB;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Logger.logError("Failed to benchmark drive speed!", e);
    if(raf != null) try {raf.close();} catch(Exception ex) {}
    return 0;
}
```