# Apache Commons Net FTP is uploading corrupted files

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to use Apache Commons Net for FTP file transfers.

Problem is files are intermittently arriving at the server corrupt. By 'corrupt' I mean that WinRAR tells me a ZIP file has an *'Unexpected end of archive'*. Sometimes the files are completely empty. I have noticed that this happens more for larger files (100kb+), however does happen for small files too (20kb).

I know for a fact that the source zip file being uploaded is valid, and is only 243kb.

I do not get any errors/exceptions from the code.

Here's the code being executed:

```
int CON_TIMEOUT = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(20); // fail if can't connect within 20 seconds
int LIVE_TIMEOUT = (int) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5); // allow up to 5 minutes for data transfers

FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.setConnectTimeout(CON_TIMEOUT);
client.setDataTimeout(LIVE_TIMEOUT);
client.connect(host);
client.setSoTimeout(LIVE_TIMEOUT);
client.login(user, pass);
client.changeWorkingDirectory(dir);
log("client ready");

File file = new File(filePath);
String name = new Date().getTime() + "-" + file.getName();

InputStream fis = null;
try
{
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    if (!client.storeFile(name, fis))
        throw new RuntimeException("store failed");
    log("store " + name + " complete");
}
finally
{
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(fis);
    try
    {
        client.logout();
        log("logout");
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        log("logout failed", e);
    }
    try
    {
        client.disconnect();
        log("disconnect");
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        log("disconnect failed", e);
    }
}
```

and some logs:

```
2010-08-10 21:32:38 client ready
2010-08-10 21:32:49 store 1281439958234-file.zip complete
2010-08-10 21:32:49 logout
2010-08-10 21:32:49 disconnect
2010-08-10 21:32:50 client ready
2010-08-10 21:33:00 store 1281439970968-file.zip complete
2010-08-10 21:33:00 logout
2010-08-10 21:33:00 disconnect
2010-08-10 21:33:02 client ready
2010-08-10 21:33:11 store 1281439982234-file.zip complete
2010-08-10 21:33:11 logout
2010-08-10 21:33:11 disconnect
2010-08-10 21:33:15 client ready
2010-08-10 21:33:25 store 1281439995890-file.zip complete
2010-08-10 21:33:26 logout
2010-08-10 21:33:26 disconnect
2010-08-10 21:33:27 client ready
2010-08-10 21:33:36 store 1281440007531-file.zip complete
2010-08-10 21:33:36 logout
2010-08-10 21:33:36 disconnect
2010-08-10 21:33:37 client ready
2010-08-10 21:33:48 store 1281440017843-file.zip complete
2010-08-10 21:33:48 logout
2010-08-10 21:33:48 disconnect
2010-08-10 21:33:49 client ready
2010-08-10 21:33:59 store 1281440029781-file.zip complete
2010-08-10 21:33:59 logout
2010-08-10 21:33:59 disconnect
2010-08-10 21:34:00 client ready
2010-08-10 21:34:09 store 1281440040812-file.zip complete
2010-08-10 21:34:09 logout
2010-08-10 21:34:09 disconnect
2010-08-10 21:34:10 client ready
2010-08-10 21:34:23 store 1281440050859-file.zip complete
2010-08-10 21:34:24 logout
2010-08-10 21:34:24 disconnect
2010-08-10 21:34:25 client ready
2010-08-10 21:34:35 store 1281440065421-file.zip complete
2010-08-10 21:34:35 logout
2010-08-10 21:34:35 disconnect
```

Note that all of these were complete within 15 seconds, and all of the resulting files on the server are corrupt.

I have also tested without setting any timeouts and the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Commons FTP defaults to Ascii file types. You want to set it to Binary when dealing with binary data like a ZIP file.

From http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

> The default settings for FTPClient are for it to use  FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE ,  FTP.NON_PRINT_TEXT_FORMAT ,  FTP.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE , and  FTP.FILE_STRUCTURE . The only file types directly supported are  FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE  and  FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE .

You want to do `setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)` before you send the file.

Comment: make sure to `ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)` after any connect method, since connect() will reset type to `FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE`.

Comment: Not only after `connect,` it must go after `login`, see [Apache Java FTP client does not switch to binary transfer mode on some servers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36349361/850848).

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

I had the same issue and solved it by calling

```java
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)
```

**before each** method `retrieveFile`, `retrieveFileStream`, `storeFile`

#### Explanation

File is corrupted, because default fileType is `FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE`. This causes the issue. If you are on linux all bytes `\n\r` (windows end of file) are changed into `\n` byte. And this corrupt the file.

To avoid this behavior you have to call `ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)`. Unfortunately, this setup is reset by each `connect` method back to `ASCII_FILE_TYPE`. 
In my case this was reset even by method `listFiles`. I guess, that this happened because I use `passiveMode` on ftpClient.

So if you want to avoid troubles **call `setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)` right before every file transfer**.

Comment: BTW: Sorry, but I have to say it: This behavior of 'Apache Commons Net FTP' is truly awful.

Comment: The mode (at least with some FTP servers) resets with `login`, so [`setFileType` has to be called after it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36349361/850848). In general, it does not reset with `listFiles`, though it's possible that your particular FTP server does. The Apache Commons Net library itself never resets the mode on its own.

Comment: Thanks - Good point - I remember, that call `setFileType` after login wasn't enough in my case. And you are right, that this issue is probably caused by the server and not by client library.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem despite specifying `binary file type` so I wrote code to validate the uploaded file via `MD5` hashing:

```
public void upload(String sourceFilePath) throws Exception
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Upload
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFilePath);
        String sourceFileHash = MD5Checksum.getMD5Checksum(sourceFilePath);
        String remoteFile = sourceFile.getName();

        try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile))
        {
            boolean successful = ftpClient.storeFile(remoteFile, inputStream);

            if (!successful)
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Upload of " + sourceFilePath + " failed!");
            }
        }

        // Download
        File temporaryFile = File.createTempFile("prefix", "suffix");
        try (OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(temporaryFile)))
        {
            boolean successful = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile, outputStream);

            if (!successful)
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Download of " + sourceFilePath + " failed!");
            }
        }

        String downloadFileHash = MD5Checksum.getMD5Checksum(temporaryFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Files.delete(temporaryFile.toPath());

        // Make sure the file hashes match
        if (sourceFileHash.equals(downloadFileHash))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`MD5Checksum.java`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class MD5Checksum
{
    private static byte[] createChecksum(String filename) throws Exception
    {
        try (InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            MessageDigest complete = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            int numRead;

            do
            {
                numRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer);
                if (numRead > 0)
                {
                    complete.update(buffer, 0, numRead);
                }
            } while (numRead != -1);

            return complete.digest();
        }
    }

    public static String getMD5Checksum(String filename) throws Exception
    {
        byte[] checksum = createChecksum(filename);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (byte singleByte : checksum)
        {
            result.append(Integer.toString((singleByte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

The `MD5` code is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/304275/3764804).