# Corrupt FTP Client Upload

Tags: java, ftp

I'm using the [`Apache FTPClient`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) library to manage the files of my web server. I noticed that when I for example upload my `SQlite` database and then download it again afterwards, the file has changed. Why does this happen?

My code for uploading via FTP is as follows:

```
public boolean uploadDatabase() throws IOException
{
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    File databaseFile = new File(databaseFileName);
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(databaseFile);
    boolean uploadedSuccessfully = ftpClient.storeFile(remoteDatabaseLocation, inputStream);
    inputStream.close();

    return uploadedSuccessfully;
}
```

If I then download the file again and compare the `MD5Sum` of the original and the downloaded one like with code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2932513/3764804), they differ. Whether I download the file using the browser or via some Java code doesn't matter so it's obvious that the `FTP` upload is corrupt and not the download.

Like pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3448556/3764804) answer, I'm already setting the file transfer mode to binary so I'm surprised why some bytes are still "randomly" inserted into the file. I compared them using the Hex Editor [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/). The resulting file hashes always consistently mismatch.

Comment: Did you try an upload with a different client?

Comment: @Fildor:
I just tried `FileZilla` and if I upload using it, the file hashes match so it works correctly. Still, I would like to figure out why the Java code is broken

Comment: Are you also downloading using FTP?  If so, does that FTP download also use binary transfer mode?

Comment: @TJSaunders:
I'm not downloading via FTP but I switched libraries. `Ftp4j` is working fine