# Java MD5 hash, how can i do?

Tags: java, md5

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Generate MD5 hash in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java)
>   [using Java to get a file's md5 checksum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/using-java-to-get-a-files-md5-checksum)

Hi boys,

how can i generate a MD5 from a file using java?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: that's a pessimistic use of "possibly" :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way.

```
public static String md5(String s) {
    MessageDigest md5;
    try {
        md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md5.update(s.getBytes());
        return new BigInteger(1, md5.digest()).toString(16);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```