# How to generate Hash of any file in java?

Tags: java, hash

How to generate Hash value of any type of file (*.doc,*.docx,*.pdf, etc...) in java?

Comment: Your question is slightly vague. If you provide some reason for wanting a hash - such as to find out if a file has the same content as some other file - then the answer would be easier to give. 

In that case, you can use an MD5 hash (Message Digest). You already have answers for that.

If you want a cryptographic hash (something that is not practical to forge) then you will not choose MD5.

Comment: Given the question as is, `public int hash(File f) {return 0;}` is a nice solution. It's unclear what the file type has to do with it. First of all, a file is a sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a related answer posted here [Getting a File's MD5 Checksum in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/using-java-to-get-a-files-md5-checksum)

You may look into ["Real's How To" Here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0416.html) and use your desired hashing algorithm like this

```
String myHash = "MD5"; // or "SHA-1" or "SHA-256"
MessageDigest complete = MessageDigest.getInstance(myHash);
```