# Get acces to a login system, Android

Tags: android, authentication, web

I'm trying to make an app that automatic download the newest file from a website and put it in a folder, from witch i can acces it. The problem is that accessing this website requires a login/password. How do i get these informations the first time i run the app, and the automaticly acces the website to see whether a new file has to be downloaded, when i click an update-button? Any material, tutorials etc. will help. I don't know where to look for this stuff.

Best regards
Jesper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a very *simple* question to answer because it's so broad and involves several different operations.

**User Credentials**

1. On startup you need to check some sort of storage (e.g: SharedPreferences, Database) for a username/password.
2. If none exists, you'll need to prompt the user to enter their username/password so you can capture and store it somewhere (e.g: SharedPreferences, Database)

[Shared Preferences Tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html)

[Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

**File Updates**

*File Modified Date* - Before deciding whether or not to download the file, you need to know when it was modified. This should help: [Android: how to know file located in web server is modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691825/android-how-to-know-file-located-in-web-server-is-modified)

*Determine if the file is newer* - After you get the last modified date of the file on the server, you need to compare it to the modified date of the file you currently have. I would suggest that whenever you download a file, you save the modified date (retrieved above) in some sort of persistant storage (Database, SharedPref).

*Downloading the File* - Here's a tutorial that should help if you decide you need to download the file on the server. 
http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2011/04/android-development-downloading-a-file-from-the-web/ - A bit complicated, but it also does the download on a background thread, which is a good idea.

Pretty vague answer, I know, but it was a pretty broad question. If you have a more specific question, we can give you a better answer.