# java how calculate hash of file data without loading file in memory (without read all bytes)

Tags: java, file, hash, md5

Having this problem, you need to somehow calculate the md5 hash of file content without reading into a byte array because:
1) file can be larger than 2GB
2) do not have enough memory to download a large file.

what can be done?
search in Google gave nothing.
thanks and sorry for my bad english

Comment: How could you hash a file's contents without somehow reading the file's contents? Can't you stream the file and calculate a bit at a time?

Comment: You can stream: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a File's MD5 Checksum in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-java)

Comment: comment by @Bill the Lizard help me, I was thinking the file is loaded into memory.