# How To Encrypt Resource Files?

Tags: java, encryption, slick2d

Hi I have a game made in Java and Slick2d and I have a folder that contains all of my resources (images, sounds, etc) and I was wondering how to encrypt them so people  can't edit them? I tried MD5 but I'm not really sure how it works and I'm not worried about people breaking into the code because I have spliced the jar into an exe file. Also if I need to know how to decrypt the files so that they can be used in the code please explain that too.

Comment: MD5 isn't an encryption algorithm. If you encrypt them you will also have to provide a key, and encrypt the key, and encrypt the key of the key, ...

Comment: And why can't you put the resources into the JAR file?

Comment: If I put the resources in the jar file then it becomes one giant exe which I don't like. I'd like a folder in the program files folder with my game name and all of the .dat files with the game launcher.exe that has the code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to protect the images/resources, all you can do is make it slightly harder. If you deliver your images/resources to the client then they can always decrypt them, after all the client has to *display* them unencrypted at some point in time.

Btw.: MD5 is a hash-algorithm, it is used to check if data is undamaged.

Comment: How do I make it slightly harder? All I want is simple encryption so the average player can't break into it. I realize it's impossible to encrypt from everyone.

Comment: Ok, then you can just use something trivial like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

Answer (score 1):

[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is a hash function which is irreversible and two input may produce the same output.

in case the content of the files is not 'secret' you can use MD5 for a verification process, this should be quite easy.

- Create a hashtabe (or just a table) with the hashes of all the resources your application uses
- Once the applet lanched create an [hash for each of the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-java) and compare it with your table, if its not the same, someone has changed the content of your jar file.

*I'd recommend to keep the hash table within the code so it will be harder to modify*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your resources, you have to decrypt them then the client can use them, because they are being used in the game.