# Java : Check equivalence of two text files?

Tags: java

There are two text files. I hope to know what is the most simplest JAVA way to check if their *CONTENTS* are equivalent each other.

On shell, I usually use `diff` command:

```
$ diff 1.txt 1.same.txt # nothing is shown if 1.txt and 1.same.txt have the same contents 
$ diff 1.txt 2.txt
4a5,6
> 20, -, 22.0
> 10, 10.0, -
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "equivalent"? Do they have to be byte-for-byte identical? Could they be the same Unicode code points but represented in different encodings? Could they differ in byte-order-mark? Could they differ in normalization form? "Equivalent" is a complicated term when it comes to text.

Comment: you could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441315/java-and-hash-algorithm-to-compare-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [google-diff-match-patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/), which implements Myer's diff.

> Robust algorithms to perform the operations required for synchronizing
>   plain text.
>
> Diff: Compare two blocks of plain text and efficiently return a list
>   of differences.
>
> Match: Given a search string, find its best fuzzy match in a block of
>   plain text. Weighted for both accuracy and location.
>
> Patch: Apply a list of patches onto plain text. Use best-effort to
>   apply patch even when the underlying text doesn't match.