# How to copy an InputStream to Apache TeeOutputStream, which expects an OutputStream?

Tags: java, file-io, io, text-files, apache-commons

I've adapted the Apache `IOUtil` [sample](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/tags/NET_1_0_0/src/java/examples/IOUtil.java) to work with the `WeatherTelnet` [sample](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/tags/NET_1_0_0/src/java/examples/weatherTelnet.java) a little differently.  While the comments for `WeatherTelnet` state that:

> The TelnetClient class used by itself is mostly intended for
>   automating access to telnet resources rather than interactive use.

I would like to split the output using Apache `TeeOutputStream`, but the [API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) branches `OutputStream` whereas `TelnetClient` "output" is in the form of an `InputStream`, so that, of course, it can be read.  Conveniently, the Apache `copyStream` utility method will copy an InputStream to an OutputStream.

1.)  How do I copy the `InputStream` to an `OutputStream` in `printKindaWorks` or `printToFile`?
2.)  How do I either write the `OutputStream` to a file, or tee it?

the trick is to do these operations *live*, **while the user interacts with the weather server**.

I did my best to look at the source code for `copyStream` and used that for reference, but it just plain doesn't work.  I haven't yet looked at the internals for the Apache implementation of tee.

The utility class:

```
package apache;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.net.io.Util;

public final class IOUtil {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(IOUtil.class.getName());

    private static void readFromConsole(final OutputStream outputStream) {
        Thread read = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int ch;

                try {
                    while ((ch = System.in.read()) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(ch);
                        outputStream.flush();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    log.warning(ioe.toString());
                }
            }
        };
        read.start();
    }

    private static void writeToConsole(final InputStream inputStream) {
        Thread write = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Util.copyStream(inputStream, System.out);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    log.warning(ioe.toString());
                }
            }
        };
        write.start();
    }

    private static void printKindaWorks(final InputStream inputStream) {
        Thread write = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                PrintStream printStream = null;
                try {
                    File file = new File("weather.log");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
                    printStream = new PrintStream(fos);
                    Util.copyStream(inputStream, printStream);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    log.warning(ioe.toString());
                }
            }
        };
        write.start();
    }

//                TeeOutputStream tee = new TeeOutputStream(inputStream, bis);   
    private static void writeToFile(final InputStream inputStream) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        final String fname = "whether.log";
        File f = new File(fname);
        f.createNewFile();
        Thread fileWriter = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                char c = 0;
                int r = 0;
                try {
                    while ((r = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                        c = (char) r;
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fname, true)));
                        out.print(c);
                        out.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(IOUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }


            }
        };
        fileWriter.start();
    }

    public static void readWriteLog(final InputStream inputStream, final OutputStream outputStream) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        readFromConsole(outputStream);
        writeToConsole(inputStream);
        writeToFile(inputStream);  //doesn't write much
  //      printKindaWorks(inputStream);       //blocks writeToConsole ?
    }
}
```

and the driver:

```
package weather;

import apache.IOUtil;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

public class Weather {

    public Weather() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        int port = 3000;
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("rainmaker.wunderground.com");
        TelnetClient telnetClient = new TelnetClient();
        telnetClient.connect(host, port);
        IOUtil.readWriteLog(telnetClient.getInputStream(), telnetClient.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

Please consider the code under the ASL.

*While I am "logging" the `InputStream` I'm not not working on a logging problem, writing to a file is just for illustration purposes.  I just want to split the `InputStream` while the user interacts with the weather server.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate a TeeOutputStream which wraps System.out and the log file.  Then create a thread which copies the telnet InputStream to the TeeOutputStream.  (you can only have a single thread consuming the telnet InputStream)

Comment: Ok, that sounds interesting!  System.out is, I think, an OutputStream and maybe a ?PrintWriter? for the branch?

Comment: @Thufir - just use a FileOutputStream instead of a FileWriter.

Comment: pardon, I just don't see **how** to possibly copy the InputStream to the TeeOutputstream.  Your point that only a single thread can consume the telnet InputStream is quite significant.

Comment: @Thufir - you already have the code to copy an InputStream to a (Tee)OutputStream.  i don't understand the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Not really what I want, would rather use Apache tee, but this does the job (clumsily):

```
package apache;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public final class IOUtil {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(IOUtil.class.getName());

    private static void readFromConsole(final OutputStream outputStream) {
        Thread read = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int ch;

                try {
                    while ((ch = System.in.read()) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(ch);
                        outputStream.flush();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    log.warning(ioe.toString());
                }
            }
        };
        read.start();
    }

//                TeeOutputStream tee = new TeeOutputStream(inputStream, bis);   
    private static void readInput(final InputStream inputStream) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Thread readInput = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                char c = 0;
                int r = 0;
                try {
                    while ((r = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                        c = (char) r;
                        printToConsole(c);
                        logToFile(c);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(IOUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }


            }

            private void logToFile(char c) throws IOException {
                String fname = "whetherOrNot.log";
                File f = new File(fname);
                f.createNewFile();
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fname, true)));
                out.print(c);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }

            private void printToConsole(char c) {
                System.out.print(c);
            }
        };
        readInput.start();
    }

    public static void readWriteLog(final InputStream inputStream, final OutputStream outputStream) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        readFromConsole(outputStream);
        readInput(inputStream);
    }
}
```