# Calculate multiple checksums from the same InputStream using DigestInputStream

Tags: java, md5, sha1, checksum, gnupg

I am trying to figure out how to read multiple digests (md5, sha1, gpg) based on the same `InputStream` using `DigestInputStream`. From what I've checked in the documentation, it seems to be possible by cloning the digest. Could somebody please illustrate this?

I don't want to be re-reading the stream in order to calculate the checksums.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could wrap a `DigestInputStream` around a `DigestInputStream` and so on recursively:

```
DigestInputStream shaStream = new DigestInputStream(
    inStream, MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1"));
DigestInputStream md5Stream = new DigestInputStream(
    shaStream, MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"));
// VERY IMPORTANT: read from final stream since it's FilterInputStream
byte[] shaDigest = shaStream.getMessageDigest().digest();
byte[] md5Digest = md5Stream.getMessageDigest().digest();
```

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc is pretty clear.  You can use clone only to calculate different intermediate digests using the same algorithm.  You cannot use `DigestInputStream` to calculate different digest algorithms without reading the stream multiple times.  You must use a regular `InputStream` and multiple `MessageDigest` objects; read the data once, passing each buffer to all `MessageDigest` objects to get multiple digests with different algorithms.

You could easily encapsulate this in your own variant of `DigestInputStream`, say `MultipleDigestInputStream` that follows the same general approach but accepts a collection of `MessageDigest` objects or algorithm names.

Pseudojava (error handling omitted)

```
MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
InputStream input = ...;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int len;
while((len = input.read(buffer)) >= 0)
{
    sha.update(buffer,0,len);
    md5.update(buffer,0,len);
    ...
}
byte[] shaDigest = sha.digest();
byte[] md5Digest = md5.digest();
```

Comment: Jim, could you show me an example, please? Also, does this mean that each digest will be keeping in memory the read bytes from the `InputStream`?

Comment: No, each digest will keep only its own work area. You will be reading the data stream once.

Comment: Right... I see what you mean now. I have to update the digest upon every read.