# 30 char md5 digest

Tags: java, md5, md5sum

I use the following code for generating **md5** for **blob data** in database.

```
md5Checksum.update(byte[] --- read from database);
String result = new BigInteger(1,md5Checksum.digest()).toString(16);
```

The checksum i obtain is varying in **length(30-32)** for different byte arrays.
For 31 char length checksum, as I understood can be an effect of the removal of leading zeros. (I handled it by adding leading zeros)

Can any one tell me why I am getting a 30 char hash in some cases?

Thanks, 
Mithun

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert a digest to a number!

Use something like:

```
byte[] b = md5Checksum.digest();
// now convert these bytes to chars
```

There are many different methods to convert byte[] to HexStrings:

```
public class HexConverter {

    // thanks to http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0596.html
    static private final String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    public String toHex(byte[] raw) {
        if (raw == null) {
            return null;
        }
        final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(2 * raw.length);
        for (final byte b : raw) {
            hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4)).append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
        }
        return hex.toString();
    }
}
```

or from [Getting a File's MD5 Checksum in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-java)
(this link also shows how to se DigestUtils from Apache Commons Codec)

```
public static String getMD5Checksum(String filename) throws Exception {
    byte[] b = createChecksum(filename);
    String result = "";

    for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
        result += Integer.toString( ( b[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. Seems working. Is there any reason why I got it as 30 char long.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the high n bits could be zero. As you convert the byte[] to a number.If n=4,then you could lose one '0' char at the beginning. 
If n=8, then you lose '00' at the beginning of your md5 hex code.