# Resume file upload/download after lost connection (Socket programming) using c program

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, client-server

I need to RESUME the upload files from client to server after connection loss using tcp/ip socket in c program I'm not sure how to go about this.(Do not want the originally sent data to be resent) I would really appreciate it if anybody could give me suggestions as to how i should implement the file resume functionality in socket server client?

Comment: Just plain TCP sockets? Then you need to implement an application-level protocol above TCP which should have such features as you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resume file upload/download after lost connection (Socket programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107380/resume-file-upload-download-after-lost-connection-socket-programming)

Comment: Big lesson here: Always search first before posting a question. Very likely the question linked to by @BradSchoening was listed in your "Related" column while you were writing this question. Always check the "Related" question first to see if they answer your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such mechanism built into TCP or UDP. You need to make your server and client agree on specific terms. If you are thinking there is no such protocol, and you want to start it from scratch, then drop the idea. You can choose `HTTP`, which provides support for `Partial-Content`. For learning purposes, you can definitely try writing one on your own. Below I implemented one such bare minimal protocol:

Rules:

1) The client sends the file offset encoded as a 32-bit `unsigned int` in network byte order (At the start of the download, 0 is sent).

2) The server reads the offset and converts to host byte order and sends the data from that particular offset.

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    /* Initialize the file */

    int fd = open("download", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);

    struct stat statbuf;
    fstat(fd, &statbuf);

    uint32_t cli_fsize = statbuf.st_size;

    /* Initialize the connection with the server */

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(55555);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) {
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Write the file offset to the server */

    uint32_t n_cli_fsize = htonl(cli_fsize);

    int off_write = 0;

    for ( ; ; ) {
        int wr_return = write(sockfd, (void*) &n_cli_fsize + off_write, sizeof(n_cli_fsize) - off_write);

        if (wr_return <= 0)
            exit(1);

        off_write = off_write + wr_return;

        if (off_write == sizeof(n_cli_fsize))
            break;
    }

    /* Read the data from the socket and write to the file */

    char fbuf[100];

    for ( ; ; ) {
        int rd_return = read(sockfd, fbuf, sizeof(fbuf));

        if (rd_return < 0)
            exit(1);
        else if (rd_return == 0)
            break;

        int wr_status = 0;

        for ( ; ; ) {
            int wr_return = pwrite(fd, fbuf + wr_status, rd_return - wr_status, cli_fsize);

            if (wr_return < 0)
                exit(1);

            wr_status = wr_status + wr_return;
            cli_fsize = cli_fsize + wr_return;

            if (wr_status == rd_return)
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    /* File initializations */

    FILE* fp = fopen("data.bin", "r+");

    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(1);

    struct stat statbuf;

    if (fstat(fileno(fp), &statbuf) != 0)
        exit(0);

    uint32_t fsize = statbuf.st_size;

    /* Initialize the server */

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP), clifd, addr_len;

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(55555);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) {
        exit(1);
    }

    listen(sockfd, 5);

    for ( ; ; ) {

        addr_len = sizeof(cliaddr);

        if ((clifd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &cliaddr, &addr_len)) < 0) {
            goto next_cli;
        }

        /* Read the 32 bit offset */

        uint32_t n_cli_fsize = 0;
        int off_read = 0;

        for ( ; ; ) {
            int rd_status = read(clifd, (void*) &n_cli_fsize, sizeof(n_cli_fsize) - off_read);

            if (rd_status == -1)
                goto next_cli;
            else if (rd_status == 0 && off_read != sizeof(n_cli_fsize))
                goto next_cli;

            off_read = off_read + rd_status;

            if (off_read == sizeof(n_cli_fsize))
                break;
        }

        uint32_t cli_fsize = ntohl(n_cli_fsize);

        /* Read from the file and write to the socket */

        char fbuf[100];

        for ( ; ; ) {
            int rd_return = pread(fileno(fp), fbuf, sizeof(fbuf), cli_fsize);

            if (rd_return <= 0)
                goto next_cli;

            cli_fsize = cli_fsize + rd_return;

            int wr_status = 0;

            for ( ; ; ) {
                int wr_return = write(clifd, fbuf + wr_status, rd_return - wr_status);

                if (wr_return <= 0)
                    goto next_cli;

                wr_status = wr_status + wr_return;

                if (wr_status == rd_return)
                    break;
            }
        }

        next_cli:

        if (clifd >= 0)
            close(clifd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

data.bin

```
$ du -h data.bin && md5sum data.bin 
149M    data.bin
6f188c0f60376fed5cfa00f55681b436  data.bin
```

**Note:** The server is always running in all the terminal sessions.

Terminal Session 1 (The client is allowed to completely download the file):

```
$ du -h download 
du: cannot access 'download': No such file or directory
$ ./client 
$ du -h download && md5sum download
149M    download
6f188c0f60376fed5cfa00f55681b436  download
```

Terminal Session 2 (The client is interrupted in the midst of the download and resumed back):

```
$ du -h download 
du: cannot access 'download': No such file or directory
$ ./client
^C
$ du -h download && md5sum download
80M     download
0f77e56c7a512abc4ccafdb890f451a1  download
$ ./client
$ du -h download && md5sum download
149M    download
6f188c0f60376fed5cfa00f55681b436  download
```

Terminal Session 3 (Running the client on a fully fetched file):

```
$ du -h download  && md5sum download 
149M    download
6f188c0f60376fed5cfa00f55681b436  download
$ ./client
$ du -h download  && md5sum download 
149M    download
6f188c0f60376fed5cfa00f55681b436  download
```

You can tweak around this base implementation, and add more features.

Comment: thanks...@Mohith Reddy something i have tried using NCFTPPUT function to send files to server port now its working fine now i need to pause and resume transfer using NCFTP.  The process is when internet is not present while transfer file it should be pause at the state and when internet comes the file transfer should resume(Do not want the originally sent data to be resent) is there any cmds in NCFTP???

Comment: @Surya Personally, I never used ``ncftpput`` but from the [man page](https://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html), it seems to support upload resumption (``-z``). Have you tried that?