# How to check if a stopword file is corrupted or wrong

Tags: java, file, char, boolean, newline

I have a file with several hundreds of stopwords. I want to be able to check if the file has been modified by a user for example or even if it is corrupted.

The way I am thinking of doing it currently is by looking if the number of lines is correct. I could also check if the total number of characters is the one expected or even have the whole stopwords list loaded in memory to check if every single one of them is in the file. All 3 of the ways I thought of seem inefficient and/or bad so I thought of asking if there is any better way of doing it.

**What I am thinking of implementing:**

```
private static final int WORD_COUNT = 354;

    public static boolean stopwordsCorrupted(File file) {
        int numOfLines = countLines(file);

        return WORD_COUNT != numOfLines;
    }
```

Comment: Check out this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum
This uses the hashfuntion of the file to check if no alterations have been made

Comment: Your suggested method will not work if someone modified your list; it only checks if someone added or removed a word. Try using a checksum.

Comment: Why don't you just compute the hash of the file, and compare against a reference?

Comment: In line with @wastl's comment, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-java

Comment: @wastl I have no idea why this did not come in my mind...So I basically find the checksum, keep it in memory and then just compare it. By the way you should add this as an answer.

Comment: @wastl Also in order to keep it in memory do I have to keep the byte array as is, therefore going to the debugger and writing down every element of the array?

Comment: Well basically yes, to know your checksum in the first place you would need to do that, or somtehing similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum This uses the hashfuntion of the file to check if no alterations have been made

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-md5-hashing-example/) you also have an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Java [WatchService API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) might be helpful for your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not that interested in live polling of a file or directory, more like an one time check.