# How to download files from Dropbox with integrity checking?

Tags: java, android, file, dropbox, dropbox-api

In my application I download video files(.mp4 and .avi) from dropbox folder to folder in sdcard. I need to play file with videoview. How I can check files integrity (equality of files from sdcard and DropBox).

Comment: upvoting as Dropbox needs to include MD5/SHA1 on their side!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend comparing file checksums. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-java) is a basic example how to get the MD5 checksum. More detailed examples with other functions can be found [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0416.html).

Comment: And how can I get md5 file checksums from Dropbox?

Comment: The Dropbox API currently doesn't offer a way to request the hash of a file.

Comment: Unfortunately, Greg is right. You can still check the size of the file though. It is not nearly as good as a hash, but it seems it is the only choice.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API now offers a hash of file data that you can use to verify a file's contents. You can find it in `FileMetadata.content_hash`. It isn't a single MD5 or SHA1, but rather a combination of SHA256 hashes of the pieces of the file. You can find more information here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/content-hash