# Moving from ANT to Maven build for Jira

Tags: java, maven, ant

We use Atlassian Jira war and customize it and then deploy the war. Ant is the preferred and suggested way of building it. But the Jenkins build takes a lot of time and we want to use a better approach to dependency management. We use apache archiva for our repository.

Earlier I planned to get the jar checksums and build a POM and then customize it.
https://github.com/myspotontheweb/ant2ivy/blob/master/ant2ivy.groovy

[Getting a File's MD5 Checksum in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-java)

That approach seemed a bit error prone, so I have now decided to read pom.properties file from jars directly and get the detials using mvn dependency:get plugin.

My question is : 
If I read and create a POM with jars , it would be a long list of dependency entries . Is there a better way to handle it like a real POM file with parent and child dependency. We want this else it will be hard work for every build/upgrade. Or just some better ideas please.

Comment: I'm the author of the ant2ivy script. Was there a problem using it? If you're already using ANT and have an Archiva repository then using ivy to manage your dependencies is the best way to go.

Comment: @Mark , I have read all your comments on the forum and the checksum approach and your code is fine. Its juts that I am on Archiva 1.3.5 which  does not support rest calls and the web services which are provided .. I will try them last. The problem I may face is that with every new version of Jira , there may be new jar and can give me problem while getting their checksum. So I plan to read the lib folder and  pom.properties file using java.util.jar.JarEntry and java.util.jar.JarFile . I am able to do that and now I have all the details I need and in Java. So its easier..

Comment: Ah... Yes the ant2ivy script was designed to leverage the Sonatype Nexus REST API calls (Never considered using Archiva). Best of luck in that case, sorry my code could not help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;

@XmlRootElement(name="artifact")
public class Artifact {

    private String groupId;
    private String artifactName;
    private String version;

    public Artifact(final String groupId,final String artifactName,final String version) {
        super();
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.artifactName = artifactName;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Artifact(final String artifactName,final String version) {
        super();
        this.artifactName = artifactName;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Artifact() {}

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name="groupId")
    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(final String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name="artifactId")
    public String getArtifactName() {
        return artifactName;
    }

    public void setArtifactName(final String artifactName) {
        this.artifactName = artifactName;
    }
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name="version")
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(final String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object other){

        try {
            if(PropertyUtils.getProperty(other, groupId).equals(PropertyUtils.getProperty(this,groupId))
                    && PropertyUtils.getProperty(other, version).equals(PropertyUtils.getProperty(this,version))
                    && PropertyUtils.getProperty(other, artifactName).equals(PropertyUtils.getProperty(this,artifactName))) {

                return true;
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return groupId.hashCode() ^ artifactName.hashCode() ^ version.hashCode();
    }
}
--------------------------------


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import artifact.model.Artifact;
import artifact.model.SearchNGResponse;

/**
 * Lucene Search ref: https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-indexer-lucene-plugin/default/docs/path__lucene_search.html
 * Repo Url used for checksums : http://repository.opencastproject.org/nexus/content/repositories/public
 * e.g. - http://repository.opencastproject.org/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?a={artifactName}&v={artifactVersion}"
 * 
 * Class to search artifact/jar GAV coordinates by reading the pom.properties file or their checksums.
 */


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name="searchNGResponse")
public class SearchNGResponse {

    private List<Artifact> artifacts = new ArrayList<Artifact>();

    @XmlElementWrapper(name ="data")
    @XmlElement(name ="artifact")
    public List<Artifact> getArtifacts(){
        return artifacts;
    }
}

-----------------------

public abstract class ArtifactDetailsExtractor {

    public abstract void generateMavenScript(final List<Artifact> artifact);
    public abstract void generateIvyScript(final List<Artifact> artifact);
    public abstract void generateGradleScript(final List<Artifact> artifact);

    private static final String searchRepo2Location ="http://repository.opencastproject.org/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?sha1={checksumString}";

    public enum ArtifactParams{
        GROUPID("groupId"),
        ARTIFACTID("artifactId"),
        VERSION("version"),
        JAR_EXTENSION("jar"),
        PROPERTIES_EXTENSION("pom.properties");

        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        private ArtifactParams(final String name) {
            this.name=name;
        }           
    }

    public List<Artifact> generateArtifactList(final String directory) throws Exception  { 

         final File folder = new File(directory);
         final File[] files = folder.listFiles();


         final Set<File> allArtifacts = new HashSet<File>();
         for (final File artifactLoaded : files) {
             final String jarFileExtension= FilenameUtils.getExtension(artifactLoaded.getName());

                if (artifactLoaded.isFile() && artifactLoaded.canRead()
                        && (jarFileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase(ArtifactParams.JAR_EXTENSION.getName()))) {
                    allArtifacts.add(artifactLoaded);
                }
         }

         final List<Artifact> artifacts=generateAndFindJar(allArtifacts);           
         return Collections.unmodifiableList(artifacts);
   }

    private List<Artifact> generateAndFindJar(final Set<File> missingArtifacts) throws IOException {

        final List<Artifact> artifacts = new ArrayList<Artifact>();

        final Set<File> availableArtifacts = new HashSet<File>();
        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        for(File f: missingArtifacts) {
            final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
            final  String checksumString = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha1Hex(is);
            final SearchNGResponse result = restTemplate.getForObject(searchRepo2Location, SearchNGResponse.class, checksumString);
            if(result!=null && !result.getArtifacts().isEmpty()) {
                artifacts.add(result.getArtifacts().get(0));    
                availableArtifacts.add(f);
            }else {     
                final Set<String> groupDetails = new HashSet<String>();
                final JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(f);                 
                final Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();

                while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                    final JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

                    if(entry.getName().contains(ArtifactParams.PROPERTIES_EXTENSION.getName())) {
                        final Properties artifactProp = new Properties();
                        final InputStream input = jarFile.getInputStream(entry); 
                        artifactProp.load(input);
                        groupDetails.add(artifactProp.getProperty(ArtifactParams.GROUPID.getName()));
                        final Artifact artifact = new Artifact(artifactProp.getProperty(ArtifactParams.GROUPID.getName()),
                                artifactProp.getProperty(ArtifactParams.ARTIFACTID.getName()),
                                artifactProp.getProperty(ArtifactParams.VERSION.getName()));
                        artifacts.add(artifact);
                        availableArtifacts.add(f);
                    }
                }                   
                jarFile.close();

            }                       
        }
        missingArtifacts.removeAll(availableArtifacts);
        generateUnavailableArtifactList(missingArtifacts);

        return Collections.unmodifiableList(artifacts);
    }

    private void generateUnavailableArtifactList(final Set<File> badArtifacts) {
        System.out.println("number of jar files failed      : "+badArtifacts.size());
        try {
            final PrintWriter  writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                      new FileOutputStream("artifact.txt"), "utf-8"));
            for(final File artifact: badArtifacts) {
                writer.println(artifact.getName());
                System.out.println("jar files failed   -----  : "+artifact.getName());
            }
            writer.close();

        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
            System.err.println("Exception while finding unavailable  dependencies , must exit process : " + ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        } 
    }

}
```

This is how I managed to get all my dependencies from an Ant lib folder to a gradle format build script. Few other ways are here too ..

http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Gradle-Make-a-3rd-party-jar-available-to-local-gradle-repository-td1431953.html