# keytool does not generate MD5

Tags: android, linux, keytool, calabash, android-keystore

in order to get my calabash running i need the debug.keystore file to have a MD5 fingerprint. I ran the following command:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -v
```

but i doesn't tell me that it created an MD5 fingerprint:

```
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Nov 21, 2016
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Issuer: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Serial number: 1
Valid from: Mon Nov 21 20:33:21 CET 2016 until: Wed Nov 14 20:33:21 CET 2046
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: B2:7E:BF:89:D0:DA:21:6F:C1:BD:1C:C1:39:FE:92:BB:3B:E9:06:18
     SHA256: D6:EC:87:68:D9:4B:6D:63:29:4B:49:F3:50:FF:96:80:7E:95:3F:41:7F:3E:69:42:44:72:3C:B7:34:9B:A6:20
Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: RSA (1024)
Version: 1
```

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: MD5 fingerprint is something you have to compute. `keytool` doesn't generate it for you. You can refer to this post on how to compute it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-java

Comment: I need to have it generated, you can't just generate it from outside an paste it in