# How to use the MessageDigest class in java?

Tags: java, hash, md5, hashcode

After checking this question ([How can I generate an MD5 hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/how-can-i-generate-an-md5-hash?rq=1)) and reading the MessageDigest documentation, I attempted to hash a simple string. But for some reason every string I pass into the method returns the same value. Below shows the code I wrote.

```
    byte[] bytesOfMessage = "helloworld".getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
    System.out.println(thedigest);
```

and is there anyway to limit the number of characters I get from the hash?

Comment: What method? Can you share all code required for reproducing the problem?

Comment: Use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(thedigest))`. Your code doesn't actually print the contents of the array.

Comment: @JornVernee when I change the code to that, the  output is an array containing integers.

Comment: @MickMnemonic that's all the code I wrote. The method I was referring to is the digest() one in line 3

Comment: What result is returned in the given example?

Comment: @TobiasWeimer  [B@5b1d2887 is the result

Comment: Thats the address of the Array, as pointed out above. You need to convert the byte array to String, like this: System.out.println(new String(thedigest));

Comment: @TobiasWeimer+OP: a digest is effectively random bits so `new String(byte[])` using the platform-dependent default charset will often discard or destroy much of the data. Better to use hex or base64, or at least specify `ISO-8859-1` (aka Latin-1) so it reliably preserves all byte values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println(thedigest);` calling the `toString()` method of your array.

Java array type does **not** override the default implementation of `Object#toString()`:

```
// from Object.java
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

that's why you see the string `[B@5b1d2887`

If you want to print an array, use java utility class `java.util.Arrays`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

But in your case, you should create a human readable string from your MD5 digest byte array. Use this simple method fo this:

```
public static String digestToReadableString(byte[] digest){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
        String s = Integer.toHexString(digest[i]);
        while (s.length() < 2) {
            s = "0" + s;
        }
        s = s.substring(s.length() - 2); // we need the last 2 chars
        sb.append(s);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/304275/1614378