# Producing checksum in Java

Tags: java, checksum, md5sum

I am implementing a code to produce a checksum from a string. I would just like to know the following below:

Why is the checksum produced directly from a string different from the checksum produced from a file containing the same string but was manually copied to the file using ctrl+c?

Edit: I'm not asking for the implementation. I'm asking why are they different to those who may have encountered this

Another example would be, why is the checksum produced from a file created by code different from the checksum produced from a file created manually where the string was copy-pasted?

But when I compared the two strings using a tool like WinMerge, it gives me the two identical strings.

Any enlightening answers are appreciated

Comment: please show us some code, otherwise this will be really hard to solve.

Comment: You can use produce md5 or sha signature. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-java

Comment: OK, so heres the thing: depending ON YOUR IMPLEMENTATION, the checksum can vary gratly, just think about having a "\n" as whitespace in your file, or an EOF (end of file) character, that you include in your checksum calculation by mistake, the string does maybe not have these - and therefor the checksum will be different

Comment: Or the encoding of the characters is differently between the string and the file (I think this is very likely)

Comment: Hi I edited my post. See if any makes a difference to your current answers

Comment: To check the line endings, check the file sizes of WinMerged "identical" files.

Comment: @DigitalJedi could you even detect an EOF and if there is, could you remove it?

Comment: It is likely that the difference you see is 100% based on the encoding of the data.  In Java, Strings are UTF-16 in memory.  If the file in question is not in UTR-16 then the CRC will differ because the data will be different.