# Java: How to search duplicate files in a folder not only by name ,but also by size and content?

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates, size

I want to create a Java application to identify duplicates. So far I can find duplicates only by name, but I also need size, file type, and maybe content. This is my code so far, using a `HashMap`:

```java
public static void find(Map<String, List<String>> lists, File dir) {
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            find(lists, f);
        } else {
            String hash = f.getName() + f.length();
            List<String> list = lists.get(hash);
            if (list == null) {
                list = new LinkedList<String>();
                lists.put(hash, list);
            }
            list.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-java) could be of help

Comment: Have you tried to introduce some FileHeader class in which you use all the elements that matter to you? On basis of this class output some checksum - sha or md5  and use it for a key in Collectors.grouping()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used MessageDigest and checked some files and find the duplicates according to all the criteria I have listed in the title and description. Thank you all.

```
private static MessageDigest messageDigest;
static {
    try {
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("cannot initialize SHA-512 hash function", e);
    }
}
```

and this is the result after implementation in the search code for duplicates

```
public static void find(Map<String, List<String>> lists, File dir) {
for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
  if (f.isDirectory()) {
    find(lists, f);
  } else {
      try{
          FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(f);
          byte fileData[] = new byte[(int) f.length()];
                fi.read(fileData);
                fi.close();
                //Crearea id unic hash pentru fisierul curent
                String hash = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest.digest(fileData)).toString(16);
                List<String> list = lists.get(hash);
                if (list == null) {
                    list = new LinkedList<String>();
                }
                //Adăugați calea către listă
                list.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                //Adauga lista actualizată la tabelul Hash
                lists.put(hash, list);

      }catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("cannot read file " + f.getAbsolutePath(), e);
            }

  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Considering 2 files equal if they have the same extension and the same file size is simply a matter of creating an object that represents this 'equality'. So, you'd make something like:

```
public class FileEquality {
    private final String fileExtension;
    private final long fileSize;

    // constructor, toString, equals, hashCode, and getters here.
}
```

(and fill in all the missing boilerplate: Constructor, toString, equals, hashCode, and getters. See [Project Lombok's @Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) to make this easy if you like). You can get the file extension from a file name by using `fileName.lastIndexOf('.')` and `fileName.substring(lastIndex)`. With lombok all you'd have to write is:

```
@lombok.Value public class FileEquality {
    String fileExtension;
    long fileSize;
}
```

Then use `FileEquality` objects as keys in your hashmap instead of strings. However, just because you have, say, 'foo.txt' and 'bar.txt' that both happen to be 500 bytes in size doesn't mean these 2 files are duplicates. So, you want content involved too, but, if you extend your `FileEquality` class to include the content of the file, then 2 things come up:

1. If you're checking content anyway, what does the size and file extension matter? If the content of `foo.txt` and `bar.jpg` are precisely the same, they are duplicates, no? Why bother. You can convey the content as a `byte[]`, but note that writing a proper `hashCode()` and `equals()` implementation (which are required if you want to use this object as a key for hashmaps) becomes a little trickier. Fortunately, lombok's `@Value` will get it right, so I suggest you use that.
2. This implies the *entirety* of the file content is in your JVM's process memory. Unless you're doing a check on very small files, you'll just run out of memory. You can abstract this away somewhat by not storing the file's entire content, but storing a hash of the content. Google around for how to calculate the sha-256 hash of a file in java. Put this hash value in your `FileEquality` and now you avoid the memory issue. It is theoretically possible to have 2 files with different contents which nevertheless hash to the exact same sha-256 value but the chances of that are astronomical, and more to the point, sha-256 is designed such that it is not mathematically feasible to intentionally make 2 such files to mess with your application. Therefore, I suggest you just trust the hash :)

Note, of course, that hashing an entire file requires reading the entire file, so if you run your duplicate finder on a directory containing, say, 500GB worth of files, then your application will require at the very least reading of 500GB, which will take some time.

Comment: If I use private static MessageDigest messageDigest;
    static {
        try {
            messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot initialize SHA-512 hash function", e);
        }
    }    ,it's the same think like you say ?

Comment: Really like Lombok, but we can use Java records instead of `@Value` now, no?

Comment: @riddle_me_this Records cannot extend, records imply all sorts of things (example: Every value must be settable during construction; no value can be generated, e.g. you can't have an always-randomly generated ID), they don't have builders yet, and lombok does other things like builders for methods-with-lots-of-args.

Comment: Valid points.  I suppose that if you needed a builder, you can use `@Builder` from Lombok on the record until that is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I made this application long ago I found some of its source code for you if you want to learn.

this method works by comparing both of files bytes.

```
public static boolean checkBinaryEquality(File file1, File file2) {
    if(file1.length() != file2.length()) return false;
    try(FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream(file1); FileInputStream f2 = new FileInputStream(file2)){
            byte bus1[] = new byte[1024],
                 bus2[] = new byte[1024];
            // comparing files bytes one by one if we found unmatched results that means they are not equal
            while((f1.read(bus1)) >= 0) {
                f2.read(bus2);
                for(int i = 0; i < 1024;i++)
                    if(bus1[i] != bus2[i]) 
                        return false;
            }
            // passed
            return true;
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        // problems occurred so let's consider them not equal
        return false;
    }
}
```

combine this method with name and extension checking and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

copy-paste-example

1. create a class that extends `File`

   ```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.Arrays;

   public class MyFile extends File {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       public MyFile(final String pathname) {
           super(pathname);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
           if (this == obj) {
               return true;
           }
           if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
               return false;
           }
           final MyFile other = (MyFile) obj;
           if (!Arrays.equals(this.getContent(), other.getContent())) {
               return false;
           }
           if (this.getName() == null) {
               if (other.getName() != null) {
                   return false;
               }
           } else if (!this.getName().equals(other.getName())) {
               return false;
           }
           if (this.length() != other.length()) {
               return false;
           }
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           final int prime = 31;
           int result = prime;
           result = (prime * result) + Arrays.hashCode(this.getContent());
           result = (prime * result) + ((this.getName() == null) ? 0 : this.getName().hashCode());
           result = (prime * result) + (int) (this.length() ^ (this.length() >>> 32));
           return result;
       }

       private byte[] getContent() {
           try (final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(this)) {
               return fis.readAllBytes();
           } catch (final IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return new byte[] {};
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. read base directory

   ```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.Iterator;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Map;
   import java.util.Map.Entry;
   import java.util.Vector;

   public class FileTest {
       public FileTest() {
           super();
       }

       public static void main(final String[] args) {
           final Map<MyFile, List<MyFile>> duplicates = new HashMap<>();
           FileTest.handleDirectory(duplicates, new File("[path to base directory]"));
           final Iterator<Entry<MyFile, List<MyFile>>> iterator = duplicates.entrySet().iterator();
           while (iterator.hasNext()) {
               final Entry<MyFile, List<MyFile>> next = iterator.next();
               if (next.getValue().size() == 0) {
                   iterator.remove();
               } else {
                   System.out.println(next.getKey().getName() + " - " + next.getKey().getAbsolutePath());
                   for (final MyFile file : next.getValue()) {
                       System.out.println("        ->" + file.getName() + " - " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       private static void handleDirectory(final Map<MyFile, List<MyFile>> duplicates, final File directory) {
           final File dir = directory;
           if (dir.isDirectory()) {
               final File[] files = dir.listFiles();
               for (final File file : files) {
                   if (file.isDirectory()) {
                       FileTest.handleDirectory(duplicates, file);
                       continue;
                   }
                   final MyFile myFile = new MyFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                   if (!duplicates.containsKey(myFile)) {
                       duplicates.put(myFile, new Vector<>());
                   } else {
                       duplicates.get(myFile).add(myFile);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that works with Java records and a Comparator.  These are immutable.  You can also adjust the semantics of `equals()` and `hashCode()` for your use case.

As @rzwitserloot notes, a drawback is lack of builder support (for which you can annotate the record with @Builder from Lombok as needed) and values must be set at construction.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public record FileEquality(String name,
                           String fileExtension,
                           long fileSize) implements Comparable<FileEquality> {

    private static final Comparator<FileEquality> COMPARATOR =
            Comparator.comparingLong(FileEquality::fileSize)
                    .thenComparing(FileEquality::fileExtension);
        
    @Override
    public int compareTo(FileEquality other) {
        return COMPARATOR.compare(this, other);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof FileEquality that)) return false;
        return fileSize == that.fileSize &&
                Objects.equals(fileExtension, that.fileExtension);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(fileSize, fileExtension);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "name=" + this.name + 
                ", size=" + this.fileSize + ", ext=" + this.fileExtension;
    }
}
```

Your choice of how you find the duplicates, as there are many ways:

```
public List<FileEquality> findDuplicates(List<FileEquality> fileList) {
    Map<FileEquality, Long> counts = fileList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    file -> file,
                    Collectors.counting()
            ));

    return counts.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And calling it:

```
List<FileEquality> equalityList = new ArrayList<>(0);
//create one for each file here
FileEquality equality = new FileEquality(yourFileName, yourFileSize, yourFileExtension);
equalityList.add(equality);

List<FileEquality> duplicates = findDuplicates(equalityList);
System.out.println("Duplicate files by size and extension:");
duplicates.forEach(System.out::println);
```

(Use a logger in your real code).