# Verifying if the file is downloaded from the trusted source

Tags: java, security

Example use case:

1. User is going to download a file (either text/binary/zip) from a trusted website
2. Provide the downloaded file to a program running on a Linux system
3. Program running on Linux will verify if the file is downloaded from the trusted website
4. If the file is downloaded from the trusted web, then the program processes the file else error

How do we validate if the file is downloaded from a trusted source?

I thought of generating some predefined text key and encoding it using the private key on the web and adding it to the file, and then the program reads the key from the file and verifies using the public key. If the predefined text matches file is from a trusted source.

Comment: why don't you compare the hash of the file with that of the trusted source?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use checksum (hash) and verify it before launch the file.

1. You need to have the checksum list before. Sometimes, the editor has a key server. So download the `SHA256SUMS` and `SHA256SUMS.gpg` files to the same directory as the file.
2. Use the command `sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK` to check if the SHA256 sum is OK.
3. If OK, you can execute/open your file without any doubt.

So in Java, [according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-java), you can calculate SHA-256 using this code :

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("file.txt"));
     DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is, md)) 
{
  /* Read decorated stream (dis) to EOF as normal... */
}
byte[] digest = md.digest();
```