# How to Generate a MD5 File Checksum

Tags: java, hash, md5, hashcode

Is there any method to generate MD5 hash of a string in Java?
I've tried something like this:
message.hashlib().md5().decode()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a File's MD5 Checksum in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304268/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-java)

Comment: *... I've tried something like this: message.hashlib().md5().decode() ...* Show your code, that doesn't look like Java it looks more like Python.

Answer (score 1):

This will hash the plain string "plaintext" using MD5.

```
    String plaintext = "This is an example text";
    MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    m.reset();
    m.update(plaintext.getBytes());
    byte[] digest = m.digest();
    BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1,digest);
    String hashtext = bigInt.toString(16);
    System.out.println(hashtext);
```